# split worksheet into different worksheets based on row content in VBA

Tags: vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYtM9.jpg)

```vb
Sub parse_data() 
  Dim lr As Long 
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim vcol, i As Integer
  Dim icol As Long 
  Dim myarr As Variant
  Dim title As String
  Dim titlerow As Integer
 
  vcol = 1 Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
  lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
  title = "A1:C1"
  titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
  icol = ws.Columns.Count

  ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

  For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
      ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
  Next

  myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
  ws.Columns(icol).Clear

  For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
      Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
      Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If

    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
  Next
 
  ws.AutoFilterMode = False
  ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you please add in more description and be more specific about the question (as per @SuperSymmetry)

Comment: I am going to filter the 1st column and copy the data between the 1st filter value to the next filter value and paste it on the next sheet with the filter value name. Plz look at the Image then its easy to understand.